# how can get two different date picker with using one UIActionSheet?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, uiactionsheet

I have multiple UITextField,i given tag's for each textField and i called datepicker while textfield didBinging Editing.i was getting different type of picker and the datepicker for remove prepossess  i was using UIActinSheet..here my problem is,i am getting datePicker only one time while i select the next TextField it will be crashing...

plz help me
i given code what i did.?

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    if (textField.tag==11) {
        NSLog(@"text fiels work out>>%d",textField.tag);

        //UIActionSheet
        pickerActionSheet  =[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
        pickerActionSheet.actionSheetStyle=UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
        //date picker    
        insertDatePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, 325, 300)];
        insertDatePicker.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeDate;
        insertDatePicker.date=[NSDate date];
        [insertDatePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        //[self.view addSubview:insertDatePicker];
        [pickerActionSheet addSubview:insertDatePicker];
        [insertDatePicker release];
        [pickerActionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
        [pickerActionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 464)];
        [pickerActionSheet release];
        insertDatePicker.hidden=NO;
        timeDatePicer.hidden=YES;


    }else 
    {
        NSLog(@"text fiels work out>>%d",textField.tag);

      //UIActionSheet
        pickerActionSheet  =[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
        pickerActionSheet.actionSheetStyle=UIActionSheetStyleDefault;

        //time picker
        timeDatePicer=[[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 230, 325, 300)];
        timeDatePicer.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeTime;
        timeDatePicer.date=[NSDate date];
        [timeDatePicer addTarget:self action:@selector(timeChanged:)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        // [self.view addSubview:timeDatePicer];
         [pickerActionSheet addSubview:timeDatePicer];
        [timeDatePicer release];
        [pickerActionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
        [pickerActionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 464)];
        [pickerActionSheet release];

        timeDatePicer.hidden=NO;
        insertDatePicker.hidden=YES;


    } 

    textFieldDidBeginEditing=textField;
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

### In .h file

Do Synthesize

```
   UIActionSheet *_pickerActionSheet;
   @property (nonatomic,retain)UIActionSheet *pickerActionSheet;
```

### In .m File

```
    @synthesize pickerActionSheet =_pickerActionSheet;

    where "pickerActionSheet" replace By "self.pickerActionSheet"
    don't release "pickerActionSheet" here
```

### In Dealloc method

```
 release Here 
   [_pickerActionSheet release];
```

Comment: dis is correct way to release the object ...See this URL how to release the object it is help to live projects  :http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/2/8/understanding-your-objective-c-self.html

Answer (score 1):

No need to hide the insertDatePicker and timeDatePicer. It will be removed as soon as you release the pickerView.

Also this is an Error remove this line.

textFieldDidBeginEditing=textField;

I have clean your code.It's working fine now.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField.tag==11) {
        NSLog(@"text fiels work out>>%d",textField.tag);
        //UIActionSheet
        pickerActionSheet  =[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
        pickerActionSheet.actionSheetStyle=UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
        //date picker    
        insertDatePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, 325, 300)];
        insertDatePicker.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeDate;
        insertDatePicker.date=[NSDate date];
        [insertDatePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        //[self.view addSubview:insertDatePicker];
        [pickerActionSheet addSubview:insertDatePicker];
        [insertDatePicker release];
    [pickerActionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
        [pickerActionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 464)];

    }else 
    {
        NSLog(@"text fiels work out>>%d",textField.tag);
        //UIActionSheet
        pickerActionSheet  =[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
        pickerActionSheet.actionSheetStyle=UIActionSheetStyleDefault;

        //time picker
        timeDatePicer=[[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, 325, 300)];
        timeDatePicer.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeTime;
        timeDatePicer.date=[NSDate date];
        [timeDatePicer addTarget:self action:@selector(timeChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [pickerActionSheet addSubview:timeDatePicer];
        [timeDatePicer release];
    [pickerActionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];

        [pickerActionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 464)];
        [pickerActionSheet release];

    } 
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

}
```